# Wring through out the house

Tags: wiring

My sister bought a house, in the bathroom a mirror was hanging and it fell down, revealing a big hole where a cabinet used to be. She found exposed wiring in the wall, would it be safe to assume that it's through out the house like that?

Comment: If in the USA and an old house, it could be "knob and tube" wiring (Google it). Otherwise add a photo to the question. It depends what you mean by exposed. Uninsulated? Or just visible plastic sheathed? or something else?

Comment: If you have a picture of the wiring, that would be helpful too.